# MVC 5 Html.ActionLink not setting autofocus?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a bootstrap modal to that comes up with an "OK" button in it. I would like to have it so that the user can then just press the enter button and have it click the button. I figure I could just set the autofocus on an ActionLink and it would work. However, I've tried a couple different things and I can't get it to work.

When I try

`<a href='@Url.Action("Index","LogOut", new { autofocus="autofocus" })' class="btn btn-success btn-lg">OK</a>`

this is what gets rendered out to the page which doesn't work

```
<a href="/LogOut?autofocus=autofocus" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">OK</a>
```

When I try this

`@Html.ActionLink("OK", "Index", "LogOut", null, new { @class = "btn btn-warning btn-lg", autofocus = "autofocus" })`

this is what gets rendered out to the page

```
<a autofocus="autofocus" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" href="/LogOut">OK</a>
```

That looks like the autofocus is set correctly but it still doesn't set the focus so I can just hit the enter button.

Comment: The `autofocus` attribute is only valid for form controls (`<input>`, `<textarea>` etc) You could try using a button and styling it as a link

Comment: So, you think using a <a> around a <button> might work?

Comment: I meant just a button, but with some javascript to handle its click event and do the redirect. But either way, it might look a bit odd having the focus rectangle around the link even if you do style it to match the css of a link

Answer (score 0):

might be because AitoFocus is not supported by the browser you are using?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp

try JavaScript

```
@Html.ActionLink("OK", "Index", "LogOut", null, new { @id = "btnauto", @class = "btn btn-warning btn-lg", autofocus = "autofocus" })

<script>
    document.getElementById("btn-auto").focus();
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your Html.ActionLink (changing the id=linkOk) with the this JS code but still it didn't focus which meant the enter key didn't work.  $('#punchModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $("#linkOK").focus();
        })

Comment: I'm using the latest Chrome for my browser.

Comment: I would have thought that would work fine as well. The only difference I had to do was try to set the focus only when the Bootstrap modal pops up which I think the JS code is correct. It's basically the same as what you have except for calling it when the modal is shown.

Comment: if your bootstrap modal is loading  a view you can do it there :-)

Comment: It's not at the moment but I might change it to give that a try. I just recently got the code to load a modal with a partial view.

Comment: I got it working perfectly in Chrome without the use of a View. However in IE it is setting focus but when you click "Enter" nothing happens and I have no idea why. Of course I have to have it working in IE. I'll have to post a separate question for that one.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions though.